# How to create arrayType for WSDL in Python (using suds)?

Tags: python, xml, arrays, wsdl, suds

**Environment:**

- Python v2.6.2
- suds v0.3.7

The WSDL (server) I work with, have the following schema sub-sections (I tried to write it clearly using plain text) -

---

***[ sub-section #1 ]***

```
searchRequest: (searchRequest){
    userIdentification = (userIdentification){
        username = ""
        password = ""
        }
    itineraryArr = (itineraryArray){
        _arrayType = ""
        _offset = ""
        _id = ""
        _href = ""
        _arrayType = ""
        }
   ...
   ...
```

---

***[ sub-section #2 ]***

```
itinerary: (itinerary){
    departurePoint = (locationPoint){
        locationId = None
        radius = None
        }
    arrivalPoint = (locationPoint){
        locationId = None
        radius = None
        }
   ...
   ...
```

---

There is no problem with 'userIdentification' (which is a "simple" type)

But, 'itineraryArr' is an array of 'itinerary', and I don't know how to use python to create XML array.

I tried few combinations, for example

```
itinerary0 = self.client.factory.create('itinerary')
itineraryArray = self.client.factory.create('itineraryArray')
itineraryArray = [itinerary0]
searchRequest.itineraryArr = itineraryArray
```

But all my trials resulted with the same server error -

```
    Server raised fault: 'Cannot use object of type itinerary as array'
    (Fault){
       faultcode = "SOAP-ENV:Server"
       faultstring = "Cannot use object of type itinerary as array"
     }
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm in the same case, with a RPC/encoded style WS and a method that contains a soap array. a print request (where `request = client.factory.create('Request')`) gives:

```
(Request){
  requestid = None
  option = 
    (ArrayOfOption){
     _arrayType = ""
     _offset = ""
     _id = ""
     _href = ""
     _arrayType = ""
  }
 }
```

The solution given by Jacques (1request.option.append(option1)1) does not work, as it ends with an error message `ArrayOfOption instance has no attribute append`.

The solution given by mcauth looks like this:

```
array = client.factory.create('ArrayOfOption')
array.item = [option1,  option2,  option3,  option4,  option5,  option6]
request.option=array
```

It works so so, as the resulting SOAP message shows no `arrayType` attribute:

```
<option xsi:type="ns3:ArrayOfOption">
```

The best solution I found is also the simplest:

```
request.option = [option1,  option2,  option3,  option4,  option5,  option6]
```

It ends with a good SOAP message:

```
<option xsi:type="ns0:ArrayOfOption" ns3:arrayType="ns0:Option[6]">
```

as expected by the server side WS.

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
itinerary0 = self.client.factory.create('itinerary')
itineraryArray = self.client.factory.create('itineraryArray')
print itineraryArray
itineraryArray.itinerary.append(itinerary0)
```

Just had to do this myself;) What helped me find it was printing to the console. That would have probably given you the following:

```
 (itineraryArray){
   itinerary[] = <empty>
 }
```

Cheers,Jacques

Answer (score 3):

For this type of structure I set an attribute called 'item' on the array object and then append the list member to it. Something like:

```
itineraryArray = self.client.factory.create('itineraryArray')
itineraryArray.item = [itinerary0]
```

Which parses and passes in fine, even for complex calls with multiple levels.